# Usar varibales php en hojas de estilo css

Tags: php, css

Tengo el siguiente código. Las variables de sesión estan llenas pero por algun motivo cuando la utilizo abajo la variable `$colorNav` la considera vacia, alguien puede ayudarme

**PHP:**

```
$colorHeader = "'".$_SESSION['_colorHeader']."'";
$colorNav = "'".$_SESSION['_colorNav']."'";
$colorLetrasNavNopulsadas = "'".$_SESSION['_colorLetrasNavNopulsadas']."'";
$colorLetrasNavPulsadas = "'".$_SESSION['_colorLetrasNavPulsadas']."'";
$colorSubNav = "'".$_SESSION['_colorSubNav']."'";
$colorFooter = "'".$_SESSION['_colorFooter']."'";
$colorFooterLetras = "'".$_SESSION['_colorFooterLetras']."'";
$colorBuscadorLetras = "'".$_SESSION['_colorBuscadorLetras']."'";
$colorCajaBuscador = "'".$_SESSION['_colorCajaBuscador']."'";
$colorWeb = "'".$_SESSION['_colorWeb']."'";
$colorHipervinculos = "'".$_SESSION['_colorHipervinculos']."'";
$fondoLogo = "'".$_SESSION['_fondoLogo']."'";
$letrasLogo = "'".$_SESSION['_letrasLogo']."'";
$colorGestutelar = "'".$_SESSION['_colorGestutelar']."'";
$colorLetrasSubNavNoPulsadas = "'".$_SESSION['_colorLetrasSubNavNoPulsadas']."'";
$colorLetrasSubNavPulsadas = "'".$_SESSION['_colorLetrasSubNavPulsadas']."'";
$colorCuadroSubNavPulsadas = "'".$_SESSION['_colorCuadroSubNavPulsadas']."'";
?>
```

**CSS:**

```
*, html {
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
}
html, body {
   height:100%;
}
body {
    font-family: Geneva,Arial,Helvetica,sans-serif;
    background: none repeat-x scroll 0 170px <?=$colorNav?> ;
    color: #333333;
}
```

Comment: Lo que puede estar pasando es que el valor que asignas en el css puede ser `'#FFF'` y css no detecta comilla simple para valores hexadecimales.

Comment: Te dejo un link, que encontré para ver si te sirve  (https://www.crazymen.net/usar-codigo-php-dentro-de-hojas-de-estilos-css/)    explica como agregar a css código php. Lo otro que puedes hacer, es hacerlo con jquery.

Comment: Imprime el valor que esta devolviendo la session y cerciorarte que no este vacía. Después verifica que el body se este imprimiendo correctamente el valor que traer la session. Puedes colocar el resultado que estas obteniendo en esta linea ( background: none repeat-x scroll 0 170px <?=$colorNav?> ;) –

Answer (score 1):

No creo que esté tomando la variable vacía, si no que `CSS` no detecta valores de color entre comillas simples.

```
background: red /* Funciona */
background: 'red' /* No Funciona */
```

La solución es no añadirle **(quitarle)** las comillas simples al Inicio y al final de tu variable de Sessión

Comment: le he quitado las comillas y sigue sin ir , alguna solucion mas?

Comment: La otra posibilidad es que no tengas ningún valor en la variable sessión , de todas formas inspecciona tu css con F12 . qué es lo que te está imprimiendo.

Comment: Gracias me equivoque a la hora de colocarlo. ya lo moví

Comment: La varibale $_SESSION['_colorHeader'] contiene en el css #ff0000 pero cuando veo la variable $colorHeader pone que no tiene ningun valor